# How to proceed with Linux source code customization?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am a non CS/IT student, but having knowledge of C, Java, DS and Algorithms. Now-a-days I am focusing on operating system and had gained some of its concepts. But I want some practical knowledge of it. Merely writing algo code in java/c has no fun in doing. I have gone through many articles where they mentioned we can customize source code of Linux-kernel.

I want to start customizing the kernel as I move ahead in the learning of OS concepts and apply the same. It will make two goals achievable  1. I will gain practical idea of the operating system 2. I will have a project.

**Problem which I face-**
1. From where to get the source code? Which source code should I download?  Also the documentation if possible.
https://www.kernel.org/
I went in there but there are so many of them which one will be better?
2. How will I customize the code once I have it?

Please give me suggestions with detail about how I should start this journey (of changing source code to customize Linux).

Moreover I am using Windows 8.

Comment: You have completely unrealistic goals.

Comment: After several months of work (using Linux, learning about it and learning more CS) you'll probably laugh at your question and the way you phrased it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend first reading *several* books on OSes and on programming. You need a broad CS culture (if possible get a CS degree)

> I am a non CS/IT student,

You'll better become one, or else spend years of work to learn all the stuff a CS graduate student has learnt.

First, you need to be *very* familiar with Linux programming on user side (application programs). So read at least [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and study the source code of several programs, including shells (and some kind of servers). Read also carefully [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). Explore the state of your kernel (e.g. thru [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)...). Look into https://kernelnewbies.org/

I also recommend learning *several* programming languages. You should in particular read [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/), an excellent introduction to programming. Read also some book like [programming language pragmatics](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/). Read something about continuation and [continuation passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). Read the [Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools#Second_edition). Read some [Introduction to Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms). Read something about [computer architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_architecture) and [instruction set architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture)

> Merely writing algo code in java/c has no fun in doing.

But the kernel is also written in C (mostly) and full of algorithmic code. What makes you think you'll get more fun in it?

> I want to start customizing the kernel as I move ahead in the learning of OS concepts and apply the same.

But why? Why don't you also consider studying and contributing to some [user](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space)-level code

I would recommend first reading a good book on OSes in general, notably [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/). Look also on [OSdev](http://www.osdev.org/).

At last, the general advice about kernel programming is *don't*. A common mistake is to try adding code inside the kernel to solve some issue that can and should be solved in user-land.

> 2. How will I customize the code once I have it?

You probably should not customize the kernel, but if you did you'll use familiar tools (a good [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) like `emacs`  or `vim`, a compiler and linker on the command line, a [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool like `make`). Patching the kernel is similar to patching some other [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). But testing your kernel is harder (because you'll often reboot).

You'll also find several books explaining the Linux kernel.

If you still want to customize the kernel you should first try to code some kernel module.

> Moreover I am using Windows 8.

This is a ***huge mistake***. You first need to be an advanced Linux user. So wipe out Windows from your computer, and **install some Linux distribution** -I recommend Debian- (and use only Linux, no more Windows). Become familiar with command line.

I seriously recommend to avoid working on the kernel as your first project. 
I strongly recommend looking at some existing user-land free software project first (there are thousands of them, notably on [github](http://github.com/), e.g. choose some [package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager) in your distribution, study its source code, work on it, propose the patch to the community). Be able to build from source code a lot of things.

Comment: No, but several books I linked to can. You need an entire book to get that explained

Comment: It would be more helpful if you can explain last paragraph bit more.

Comment: I believe you'll be able to understand my answer after having installed Linux and used it (notably on the command line) for several months. You need many years of work before patching the kernel.

Comment: Don't frighten youngsters by years of experience in CS, just recall that cfs scheduler algorithm had been written by MD.

Answer (score 2):

A wise man once said you "must act your way into right thinking, as you cannot think your way into right acting". In your case, you'll need to act as an experienced programmer would act, which means before we write any code, we need to answer some questions.

- What do we want to change?
- Why do we want to change it?
- What are the repercussions of this change (ie what other functions - out of all the 10's of millions of lines of source code - call this function)?
- After we've made the change, how are we going to compile it? In other words, there is a defined process for this. What is it?
- After we compile our new kernel/module, how are we going to test it?

A good start, in addition to the answer  that was just posted, would be to run LFS (Linux from Scratch). Get a successful install of that and use it as a starting point.

Now, since we're experienced programmers, we know that tinkering with a 10M+ line codebase is a recipe for trouble; we need a bit more direction than that. Here's a list of bugs that need to be fixed: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/buglist.cgi?chfield=%5BBug%20creation%5D&chfieldfrom=7d
I, for one, would be glad to see the one called "AUFS hangs on fanotify" go away, as I use AUFS with Docker on a daily basis.

If, down the line, you decide you'd rather hack on something besides the kernel, there are plenty of other options.

Comment: I am a student, need directions to go. As Basile mentioned I need to have good hands on Linux and some prior knowledge before to begin, if you have any suggestions in the same direction please mention. I want to have a good hold.

Answer (score 2):

1. From your question it follows that you've already gained some concepts of an operating system. However, if you feel that it's still insufficient, it is OK to spend more time on learning. An operating system (mainly, a kernel) has certain tasks to perform like memory management (or memory protection), multiprogramming, hardware abstraction and so on. Neither of the topics may be neglected - they are all as important. So, if you have some time, you may refer to such useful books as "Modern Operating Systems" by [Andrew Tanenbaum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_S._Tanenbaum). Special books like that will shed much light on all important aspects of a modern OS. Suffice it to say, Linux kernel itself was started by [Linus Torvalds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds) because of a strong inspiration by [MINIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MINIX) - an educational project by [A. Tanenbaum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_S._Tanenbaum).
2. Such a cumbersome project like an OS kernel (BSD, Linux, etc.) contains lots of code. Many people are collaborating to write or enhance whatever parts of the kernel. So, there is a common and inevitable need to use a [version control system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control). So, if you have an intention to submit your code to the kernel in future, you also have to have hands on with version control. Particularly, Linux relies on [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) SCM (software configuration management - a synonym for `version control`).
   So, once you have some knowledge of Git, you can install it on your computer and download Linux source code: `git clone https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git`
3. Determine your goals at Linux kernel modification. What do you want to achieve? Perhaps, you have a network card which you suspect to miss some features in Linux? Take a look at the other vendors' drivers and make an attempt to fix the driver of interest to include the features. Of course, this will require some knowledge of the HW, and, if the features are HW dependent, you will unlikely succeed to elaborate your code without special knowledge. But, in general, - if you are trying to make an enhancement, it assumes that you are an experienced Linux user yourself. Otherwise, how will you understand that some fixes/enhancements/etc. are required? So, I can't help but agree with the proposal to postpone Windows 8 for a while and start using some Linux distribution (eg. [Debian](https://www.debian.org/)).
4. If you succeed to determine your goals (eg. if you find a paper describing some desired changes in Linux kernel or if you decide to enhance some device drivers / write your own), you will be able to try it hands on. However, you still might need some helpful books, but, in this case, some Linux-specific ones. Also, writing C code for the kernel itself will require one important detail - you will need to comply with a so called [coding standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_conventions), otherwise Linux kernel maintainers will not be able to accept your patches.

So, I made an attempt to outline some tips based on your current question. Of course, the job of kernel development has far more broad prerequisites, but these are which are just obvious.

Comment: I am following Galvin Gagne as a beginner. Isnt it good to go with?

Comment: You know, it's a tough question. I can't say that some book is better than other books. If you like your current book, make use of it. But it's *always* worth reading additional books. Good kernel devs are fighting tooth and nail to keep their knowledge up to date. So, all in all, it's OK to go with, but consider reading more books in future, including the one which I recommend :)